# How to prevent child component style from affect parent in Angular 7 when importing Bootstrap css

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-4, angular7

I have a component that implements a lib that requires Bootstrap. But I don't want to apply Bootstrap to the rest of the project. So I imported the Bootstrap CSS inside the component style file. When I use this component inside another component, the style applies to the entire page including to other pages after I access the page that includes the component. I already have tried to use ViewEncapsulation options, but unsuccessfully.

Comment: Have you tried css :root pseudo-class?

Comment: If you don't use ViewEncapsulation.None, this must not happen, check your code and your angular.json

Comment: @Eliseo what exactly should I check on angular.json?

Comment: @FelipeBelluco, in Angular.json you can add general styles, normally you only has under "tag" styles an unqique file: src/styles.css, be carefull if you has add bootstrap.css